# multiple optional parameters - how to use route and template

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

Since I am starting with Play framework (2.1.3)
this seems like a simple questions to me but I haven't figured out a solution, yet.

Maybe there is a complete other approach to get it working and that's why I am not finding examples on this.

I want to show a list of values based on three optional filter values.

My Controller accepts three parameters

```
public static Result index(Integer filterA, String filterB, String filterC)
```

The route sending the request to it

```
GET / controllers.Teachers.index(filterA :Integer = null, filterB = null, filterC = null)
```

this will accepts URLs like `localhost:9000/?filterA=10&filterB=20&filterC=test`

The filters should be selectable through three list by just clicking on a value, so my link within the template looks like

```
<a href="@routes.Teachers.index()?filterA=10">Value for filter A</a>
<a href="@routes.Teachers.index()?filterB=20">Value for filter B</a>
<a href="@routes.Teachers.index()?filterC=test">Value for filter C</a>
```

I think this is not the "play way" to do it since I take play out of the control of generating the URL. Additionally, when I want to set two filters together, I have to pass the selcted filter to my template (parameter or session) and have complex links like this:

```
<a href="@routes.Teachers.index()?filterA=10&filterB=@selectedB&filterC=@selectedC">Value for filter A</a>
<a href="@routes.Teachers.index()?filterA=@selectedA&filterB=20&filterC=@selectedC">Value for filter B</a>
<a href="@routes.Teachers.index()?filterA=@selectedA&filterB=@selectedB&filterC=test">Value for filter C</a>
```

So in my opinion, this is a really common usecase but I haven't figured out how to do this easily within play :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call the action by passing arguments to it in your template:

```
<a href="@routes.Teachers.index(10, null, null)">Value for filter A</a>
<a href="@routes.Teachers.index(null, 20, null)">Value for filter B</a>
<a href="@routes.Teachers.index(null, null, "test")">Value for filter C</a>
```

So you don't have to put default values in your `routes` file:

```
GET / controllers.Teachers.index(filterA :Integer, filterB :Integer, filterC: String)
```

Or if you want to keep them optional, you can call them if your template with:

```
<a href="@routes.Teachers.index(filterA = 10)">Value for filter A</a>
<a href="@routes.Teachers.index(filterB = 20)">Value for filter B</a>
<a href="@routes.Teachers.index(filterC = "test")">Value for filter C</a>
```

with the following route:

```
GET / controllers.Teachers.index(filterA : Int ?= 0, filterB ?= null, filterC ?= null)
```

Note, that Java's `Integer`, should be a Scala's `Int` in the route file:

```
public static Result index(Integer filterA, String filterB, String filterC) {
    if (filterA == 0 && filterB == null && filterC == null) {
        return badRequest("No filter data...");
    }
    return ok("some filtering");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, since I want the parameters to be optional, I tried you second solution but got a compilation error within my template: 
too many arguments for method index: ()play.api.mvc.Call

Comment: I called the Action from the wrong controller (it should be `Teachers` instead of `Application` no ?)

Comment: @ThomasK check my edit, that works, nico_ekito I hope you don;t mind :)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot nico_ekito and biesior! I edited the Teacher/Application controller in my questions so everything is consistent. I used Integer instead Scala Int and I had a stupid problem with the optional parameters :) Since I am filtering for teachers with courses and school classes, one of my parameter was named "class"... which leads to another compilation error "illegal start of simple expression"
=> naming variables "class"... don't do that at home :D